# Ubuntu loading purple screen hang

Tags: virtualbox

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 through Virtual Box. Initially it worked ok for a couple of weeks however now Ubuntu hangs up on Purple screen before that the following error shows on black screen 
*ERROR* Failed to send log.

Need help

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings in the virtualbox
Then Go to Display
The change the Graphic controller to VBOX VGA.

Ubuntu will start working